# ClariS and Fushimi Tsukasa

Tags: oreimo, claris, eromanga-sensei

Watching Ero-manga Sensei's song (forgot if it was the opening or the ending), I immediately noticed that it was sung by ClariS. Now, interestingly, both Ero-manga Sensei and Ore no Imouto ga Konnani Kawaii Wake ga Nai are written by Fushimi Tsukasa. Both also has their theme song sung by ClariS.

Is this just a coincidence, or there's more than meets the eyes?

Comment: And both light novel are illustrated by Hiro Kanzaki (Also responsible for the character design for anime) who also happened to draw character illustration for ClariS

Comment: ClariS also had a cameo in the _Ore Imo_ novels and got the _To-Love-Ru_ treatment from Kyousuke.