# Which music artist and manga artist/light novelist has the longest number of episodes working together?

Tags: anime-production

Considering [my other question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39878/claris-and-fushimi-tsukasa), I started to wonder, which pair of music artist and manga artist/light novelist has the longest number of episodes working together?

For example, ClariS and Fushimi Tsukasa has worked together for 32 episodes in Ore no Imouto ga Konnani Kawaii wake ga Nai (16 in each season) as ClariS provided the OP/ED (forget which one) song for both seasons of it.

Comment: Can't confirm if it's the longest episodes but [Kumiko Osugi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumiko_%C5%8Csugi) sung Doraemon opening theme song [Doraemon no Uta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doraemon_no_Uta) for 1199 episodes or more than 13 years

Comment: It was opening song by the way, for both seasons